# Make Azure DocumentDB do not return service fields

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

I'm using SQL-like sytax for Azure DocumentDB in node app. Here is method code

```
client.queryDocuments(collection._self, "SELECT * FROM root").toArray(function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
        callback(err);
    } else {
        callback(null, results);
    }
});
```

and response

```
[
{
    "id": "test1",
    "name": "Kate",
    "email": "test@mail.com",
    "brands": [
        "AAAA",
        "BBB",
        "CCCi"
    ],
    "_rid": "WedNAN3lZgABAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/WedNAA==/colls/WedNAN3lZgA=/docs/WedNAN3lZgABAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"00001b00-0000-0000-0000-56fff6c60000\"",
    "_ts": 1459615430,
    "_attachments": "attachments/"
}
```

]

Is there any way to make DocumentDb don't retrun service fields (_rid, _self, _etag, _ts, _attachments), but not writing  all non-service fields in select clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

Just using a query, there is no way to get back all fields except system fields using a query but without listing each non-system field in the SELECT clause. However, you can do it with a stored procedure that filters them before returning or using a UDF to do the same thing (see below).

**Update**

Others have suggested removing them after the list returns, but after thinking about this some more, it is possible to do this with a query and a simple user defined function (UDF):

```
function stripUnderscoreFields (o) { 
  output = {};

  for (key in o) {
    value = o[key];
    if (key.indexOf('_') !== 0) {
      output[key] = value;
    }
  }
  return output 
}
```

Then use the UDF in a query like this:

```
SELECT VALUE udf.stripUnderscoreFields(c) FROM collection c
```

Comment: Are you sure that he/she can't you solve this using DocumentDB _Query Projections_ in node.js, I'm only familiar with .NET and there you can.

Comment: If you can specify the fields, then it is possible. I'm not familiar with Query Projections (unless you mean self joins). Is that functionality found in the .NET SDK rather than in DocumentDB itself? In general though, I encourage node.js users to take advantage of the unique db-side programming capability of DocumentDB. Node.js/JavaScript developers can move code from the app server or even the browser into the db with little effort. They can test in-db execution of sprocs right inside of node.js. They can push npm packages (some) into their sprocs. It's a very natural environment for them.

Comment: See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-sql-query/ for DocumentDB query projections.

Comment: Can you post how you'd do it in .NET? That might give some clue. The link you posted just referred to "projections" as a feature of the SELECT clause and I don't see how you can get every field but the system ones without specifying each field using that.

Comment: Use [CreateDocumentQuery()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.DocumentQueryable.CreateDocumentQuery);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true#M:Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.DocumentQueryable.CreateDocumentQuery%28Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient,System.String,Microsoft.Azure.Documents.SqlQuerySpec,Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.FeedOptions,System.Object%29) like so  `DocClient.CreateDocumentQuery(resourceSelfLink, "SELECT name, email FROM root", feedOptions)`

Comment: In your example, you are specifying the fields (name and email). xander27 explicitly asked, "but not writing all non-service fields in select clause".

Comment: Did not read that before; that would be harder to achieve afaik.

Comment: For now my best approach to wite method which will postporcess each record and remove service fields. But its looks like dirty hack

Comment: What's wrong with leaving them in there? Native and library objects are often annotated with underscore fields.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Azure DocumentDB REST API [`Query Documents`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt670897.aspx), these fields are generated by system, please see the section `Response - Body` of the API doc to know the properties of document.

The DocumentDB SDK for Node.js wrapped the related REST APIs, so you can try to filter them in the callback function if you don't want to return.