# Do CosmosDB built-in metadata fields do anything on update?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Every document in CosmosDB contains these special automatic metadata fields or service fields prefixed with underscore , i.e.:

```
{
    "id": "some logical key",
    "_rid": "SOMEAOJgMwGmJwEAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/SOMEAA==/colls/SOMEAOJgMwE=/docs/SOMEAOJgMwGmJwEAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"3f004486-0000-0c00-0000-5e2ea95d0000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1580116317
}
```

There is enough information about the meaning of their values (i.e. ["Properties of documents"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/databases-containers-items#azure-cosmos-items)) and uses (i.e. ["Optimistic concurrency control"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/database-transactions-optimistic-concurrency#optimistic-concurrency-control). Also, how to [remove or exclude them from documents](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36376209/331325), etc.

Setting `_etag` and optimistic concurrency scenario aside, it is less clear, what is their effect when a document with such fields being set is being saved back to collection.

In my testing I don't see them doing anything, and even if intentionally modified, the user-set values are always silently reset on update, to whatever CosmosDB service considers the correct state. Currently I see no point in having them in the saved model at all.

**Is it always safe to save a document without such service fields? 
Could it have any undesirable side-effects and in what circumstances?**

Comment: I'm afraid that this kind of question is more suitable to ask the official cosmos DB team.

Comment: Askcosmosdb email kindly directs questions to SO: "Please submit your question tagged with [azure-cosmosdb] and we will respond to you there!"

Answer (score 2):

Due to a lack of authoritative answer, I'll answer it using my experience from field.

**DO** drop `_rid`, `_self`, `_attachments`, `_ts` on read, or do not include them in you model. Documents can be successfully written without them, and I have NOT witnessed any RU or perf hit for doing so. They just waste memory in client for no tangible gain.

**CONSIDER** dropping `_etag` unless you intend to use it later as precondition for manipulating the document.